# mktime returns wrong dates

Tags: php, date, mktime

I'm trying to get a date from a html, and i use mktime to convert it to a day like: `Monday`

```
$dayisarr=date( "l", mktime(0,0,0, $duedt[1], $duedt[0],$duedt[2] ));
```

when i print it , it returns me a wrong day...like `Friday` which is wrong..
i tried to change the `l` to `r`, which prints the whole date and it printed me the wrong   month and year.. ive searched for a long long time in the internet and i didnt find nothing.

Comment: please check if your parameters are correct, ie that the $duedt[] is passing variables. [refer to this manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Comment: What's your default timezone, and what values are you passing? check your ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$dayisarr=date( "l", strtotime($duedt[2] . '-' . $duedt[1] . '-' . $duedt[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use mktime? [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) is far simpler.

```
$duedt = array(8, 14, 2013);
$dayisar = (new \DateTime())->setDate($duedt[2], $duedt[0], $duedt[1])->format('l');
var_dump($dayisar);
```

Output:-

```
string 'Wednesday' (length=9)
```